# Function which takes an int pointer * as an argument and returns a struct. Storing data in struct struct* and printing results

Tags: c, struct

I'm running into this problem which I think should not happen:
Here are the errors I'm getting.
Sorry for bad formatting, coding on notepad and cntr c&v to compiler (tend to do this from time to time)

```
~/workspace/Exam1 $ gcc -g payload.c -o payload
payload.c: In function ‘main’:
payload.c:63:31: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     struct payload* calcVal = getCalc(arr, num);
                               ^
payload.c:65:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     printf("OddSum : %d\n", calcVal->sumOdd);
                                    ^
payload.c:66:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     printf("Even Count : %d\n", calcVal->evenCount);
                                        ^
payload.c:67:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     printf("Minimum : %d\n", calcVal->min);
                                     ^
payload.c:68:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     printf("Maximum : %d\n", calcVal->max);
```

I honestly do not understand what the problem is and why I keep running into this. Am I passing struct wrong?

```
#include<limits.h> //for min/max 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct payLoad{
    int sumOdd;
    int evenCount;
    int min;
    int max;
};

struct payLoad* getCalc(int *arr, int n){
    int i = 0;
    int min= INT_MAX;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0;
    int even = 0;
    struct payLoad* calcVal = malloc(sizeof(struct payLoad));  //watch spelling


    for(i=0;i <n;++i){
        if(arr[i]%2==0){
            ++even;
        }
        if (arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

    if (arr[i] > max){
        max = arr[i];
    }
    if(arr[i]%2==1){
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }

    calcVal->sumOdd = sum;
    calcVal->evenCount = even;
    calcVal->max = max;
    calcVal->min = min;

    return calcVal;

}

int main(){

    int num; 
    int i=0; 
    //int min= INT_MAX:
    //int max = INT_MIN: 
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of array element: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i <num;++i){
        printf("Enter the value: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    struct payload* calcVal = getCalc(arr, num);

    printf("OddSum : %d\n", calcVal->sumOdd);
    printf("Even Count : %d\n", calcVal->evenCount);
    printf("Minimum : %d\n", calcVal->min);
    printf("Maximum : %d\n", calcVal->max);
}
```

Edit: fixed typos and spellings, removed link, cntr c&v errors

Comment: `sizeof(struct payload)`->`sizeof(struct payLoad)` spelling.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Be clear.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and output, copy & paste it here like you had in the first place. The error says that it cannot parse the file, you have some typos in your code. coderredoc pointed them out.

Comment: Your code is awfully formatted, some of these error (like the missing `{` after the `if`) would haven been obvious if you indent the code properly. I fixed the indentation in your code and now you've broken it again.

Comment: @Pablo I'm sorry. Here, looks better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is having several typo's, like at several places you have:

```
struct payload
          ^
```

`payload` should be `payLoad`.

Here:

```
if(arr[i]%2==1)
    sum = sum + arr[i];
}
```

You forgot to put `{`. It should be:

```
if(arr[i]%2==1) {
    sum = sum + arr[i];
}
```

In `main()`:

```
int num,
```

Instead of `,` it should be `;`.

Again in `main()`:

```
printf("OddSum : %d\n", calcVal->oddSum);
```

Look at your `struct payLoad` declaration and you will find that it is having a member `sumOdd` and not `oddSum`.

The compiler must be reporting all these as errors. Take a close look at them, try to identify the cause, fix it and build it again.

Whatever memory you are allocating dynamically you should free it. Once the program terminates the memory owned by it will be freed automatically but as a good programming practice, you should explicitly `free` the memory allocated dynamically once you are done with it.

Comment: replace the screenshot and fixed spelling and typos

Comment: @WadeWilson: have you made the changes that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: figured it out. Thank you